# WebSocket client-side returning error 1006 on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this same problem and I am new to Node js so I don't know how to fix it. I am trying to make a WebSocket server to port 8000 with and I am using WSS. I don't have any errors on the server and ran even without connection to the server it still gave the error so I know it is on the client-side.

The error reason is 0 The error code is 1006 (I got the e.reason from onerror)

I am using google chrome and i don't know if it works on other browsers.
app.js

```
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      req.on('data', function(e) {
        res.write(e);
      })
      req.on('close', function() {
        console.log('CONNECTION CLOSED')
      })
    }).listen(8000);
```

index.html

```
<p id="status">Connecting...</p>
<input id="message" />
<button id="submit">Send</button>
<script>
  var s = new WebSocket("wss://StarliteServer.cs641311.repl.run:8000", ["soap", "wamp"]);
  s.onopen = function() {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Connected";
  }
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    s.send(document.getElementById("message").value);
  });
  s.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
  }
  s.onclose = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "ERROR: "+e.code
  }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser client reports close code 1006, then you should be looking at the websocket.onerror(evt) event for details.

Close Code 1006 is a special code that means the connection was closed abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation.

Know more from below link

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4.1

Comment: But how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a webrtc project. I observed when the user switched to another page or the chrome goes to background process in Android this happens. Or in the case of incomming call in Android Phone.